# What does $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow [0,1]\times[0, 1]$ mean?

Tags: functions

I'm not sure what the right hand side of the function definition stands for? Does that mean that the output is a matrix?

Comment: $[0,1]=\{x:0\le x\le 1\}$ and $A\times B=\{(a,b):a\in A,\, b\in B\}$.

Comment: Like $f(x)=(x^2,x)$

Comment: No it means you are carrying elements in the interval $[0,1]$ and mapping it to the unit square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output lives in the set $\{(x,y) | x \in [0,1], y\in [0,1] \}$.

In LaTeX you should use "\times" rather than a capital X to represent this - it's called a Cartesian product of two sets.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate in more layman terms, the function maps any number between 0 and 1 inclusive to a point in the unit square.